# Error in loading OpenCV from Python on OS X Marericks

Tags: c++, python, macos, opencv

I've correctly build OpenCV in OS X and I can use it with C++,
however, when I try to load the cv2 module from Python, I get this error:

> > > import cv2
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >       ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so, 2): Symbol not found: _*ZN2cv11FileStorageC1ERKSsiS2*
> > >         Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so
> > >         Expected in: lib/libopencv_core.2.4.dylib
> > >        in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cv2.so

I have the same issue both with python and opencv installed from macports and when compiling OpenCV by my self. I have tried to use Python 2.7.5 and 2.7.6 and opencv 2.4.5 and 2.4.6.1